# Trouble understanding my errors when trying to create my MongoDB database connection on my javascript server using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am currently taking a web course and am almost always struggling to debug my code and the errors Node returns don't seem to help.

I am creating a web server and trying to create username and password authentication with MongoDB and JavaScript. When I call my initialize function I get a wack load of errors. I know it is coming from my Database initialization function because when I take it out of my initial server initialization I get no errors. For the most part this code comes from my specific assignment design document so I am not looking for anything that's more efficient etc.

Working Code without MongoDB function:

```
data.initialize().then(function(){
app.listen(HTTP_PORT, function(){
    console.log("app listening on: " + HTTP_PORT)
});
}).catch(function(err){
console.log("unable to start server: " + err);
});
```

Code that isn't working:

```
data.initialize().then(dataServiceAuth.initialize).then(function(){
app.listen(HTTP_PORT, function(){
    console.log("app listening on: " + HTTP_PORT)
});
}).catch(function(err){
console.log("unable to start server: " + err);
});
```

DataServiceAuth.initialize:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var userSchema = new Schema({
    "userName": {
        unique: true,
        type: String
    },
    "password": String,
    "email": String,
    "loginHistory": [{ "dateTime": Date, "userAgent": String }]
});

let User; //to be defined on new connection

module.exports.initialize = function () {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        let db = mongoose.createConnection("mongodb://<Removed username>:<removed password>@ds017193.mlab.com:17193/web322_a6");
        db.on('error', (err) => {
            reject(err); // reject the promise with the provided error
        });
        db.once('open', () => {
            User = db.model("users", userSchema);
            resolve();
        });
    });
};
```

and last but not least all the errors

```
(node:6968) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Username contains an illegal unescaped character
    at parseConnectionString (C:\Users\Jasper\Desktop\School\web322\WEB322-A5-solution\node_modules\mongodb\lib\url_parser.js:280:11)
    at parseHandler (C:\Users\Jasper\Desktop\School\web322\WEB322-A5-solution\node_modules\mongodb\lib\url_parser.js:119:14)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\Jasper\Desktop\School\web322\WEB322-A5-solution\node_modules\mongodb\lib\url_parser.js:25:12)
    at connect (C:\Users\Jasper\Desktop\School\web322\WEB322-A5-solution\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:874:3)
    at connectOp (C:\Users\Jasper\Desktop\School\web322\WEB322-A5-solution\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:269:3)
    at executeOperation (C:\Users\Jasper\Desktop\School\web322\WEB322-A5-solution\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:419:24)    at MongoClient.connect (C:\Users\Jasper\Desktop\School\web322\WEB322-A5-solution\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:260:10)
    at Promise (C:\Users\Jasper\Desktop\School\web322\WEB322-A5-solution\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:427:12)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (C:\Users\Jasper\Desktop\School\web322\WEB322-A5-solution\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:424:19)
    at Mongoose.createConnection (C:\Users\Jasper\Desktop\School\web322\WEB322-A5-solution\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:167:17)
    at C:\Users\Jasper\Desktop\School\web322\WEB322-A5-solution\data-service-auth.js:18:27
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at module.exports.initialize (C:\Users\Jasper\Desktop\School\web322\WEB322-A5-solution\data-service-auth.js:17:12)
    at <anonymous>
(node:6968) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside
of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:6968) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: It said your username contains illegal (unescaped) characters. You've removed your username, so we can't tell which one it might be.

Comment: The username is Frenchy468

Comment: Wow so this function was taken directly from my design document from my professor. the <> signs in my createConnection where meant to show where to write your username and password and meant to be removed after. I assume it was syntax.